# Flexbox columns direction from right to left

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLsuA.jpg

What I have: https://jsfiddle.net/tzayffsv/

I use flexbox with params: flex-direction: column, flex-wrap: wrap. The Problem is that items going outside the screen when wrapping... Any ideas how to do this using flexbox (or mbe other ideas)? I don't look for solutions with javascript and positioning items as absolute..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that natively with flexbox. That's not the way wrapping works...I'd be interested to see a solution. If you reverse the structure you can manage something similar though - https://jsfiddle.net/tdy4rbw5/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works.  `flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;`

```css
    .box {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    background:grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    .item {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 40%;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      <div class="item">A</div>
      <div class="item">B</div>
      <div class="item">C</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should use the op structure and eventually fork a fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/tzayffsv/3/ ;) to show that flex handle this as wished

Answer (score 5):

This is not directly related to flexbox, you only need to set the direction of the text to be right-to-left. This can be easily achieved with

```css
.container {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```css
.container {
  direction: rtl;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  height: 600px;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #618ae4;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Grammka do not forget that you might have to reset direction:ltr;  for children

Comment: Yes, otherwise the default `text-align: start` will be right, and other similar things.