# Right-to-left, top-to-bottom masonry layout with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to achieve something like this with **pure CSS**?

[image: Example]

As you can see, it is like a regular top-to-bottom masonry layout, but the order is reversed.

Comment: Try using `flexbox`. It's probably the easiest and fastest way to get this working. Here's a great guide I would recommend if you're new to `flexbox` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried to use `flex-wrap` but no luck last time. I'll probably try again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can achieve this using `flexbox` as in the following example:

#### HTML

```html
<div class='box'>
    <div class="small box-item">1</div>
    <div class="big box-item">2</div>
    <div class="big box-item">3</div>
    <div class="medium box-item">4</div>
    <div class="small box-item">5</div>
    <div class="medium box-item">6</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
        .box-item {
            margin: 0;
            border: 5px solid white;
            background-color: violet;
        }

        .small { height: 10vh; }
        .medium { height: 30vh; }
        .big { height: 60vh; }

        .box {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
            max-height: 100vh;
        }
```

The result will be like this:

[image: Screenshot]

See also [Flexbox columns direction from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231031/flexbox-columns-direction-from-right-to-left)